# How to Pivot data from distinct rows into a single row under different columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I Have a table called Value that's associated with different 'Fields':

```
 VALUE_ID      VALUE_TX       FIELD_NAME     SUB_ID
     1          Yes             Adult           1
     2          18              Age             1
     3          Black           Eye Color       1 
     4          Brown           Hair Color      1
     5          Female          Gender          1
```

I have a table called Submitted that looks like the following:

```
 SUB_ID      Submitted_Name
    1         TEST_RUN
```

I need a result set that Looks like this:

```
 Submitted_Name    Adult      Age     Eye Color     Hair Color      Gender
    TEST_RUN       Yes        18      Black         Brown           Female
```

I've tried the following:

```
 SELECT * FROM (
                 select value_Tx, field_name, sub_id
                   from VALUE
               )
         PIVOT (max (value_tx) for field_name in ('Adult', 'Age', 'Eye Color', 'Hair Color', 'Gender')
               );
```

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know if I need to add any additional details / data.

Thanks in advance!

- List item

Comment: And how does your query not work?

Comment: convert `max value_tx` to `max(value_tx)`

Comment: Whoops, typo; i meant max(value_Tx). @GordonLinoff: I am  not sure if I am supposed to use SUM or MAX for the pivot. The issue is that I have both Text and Numeric values in my VALUE Column...

Comment: @JohnWick . . . You have only string values.  A column can only have a single type.

Comment: ah I confused myself. sorry about that.